# How to make a mute button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, voice

Audio is BGM, and textbox is effects sound.
Is there a way to mute audio and voice?

Currently, i can mute BGM by pressing the ter button.
Could you tell me one of the two ways?

First, can I mute audio and voice with the "#ter" button?
Second, Is there any way to mute the voice by just pressing the "textbox_mute" button?

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var playPauseBTN = document.getElementById('ter');
var count = 0;
let voice;

$("#ter").on("click", function playPause(){
    if(count == 0 ) {
        count = 1;
        audio.play();
        playPauseBTN.innerHTML="Pause &#9208;"
    } else {
        count = 0;
        audio.pause();
        playPauseBTN.innerHTML="play &#9658;"
    }
});

$(".textbox").on("click", function(){
  onSelectFocus(i++);
  $(".mv .bg").attr("src", "images/bg/" + wallPaper[i]+ ".png");
  $(".character-thumb img").attr("src", "images/character/" + chaImage[i]+ ".png");
  if (voice !== undefined) voice.pause();
  let v = "./voice/" + soundNum[i] + ".mp3";
  voice = new Audio(v);
  voice.volume = 0.3;
  voice.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <audio id="audio" loop>
  <source src="https://ia801402.us.archive.org/3/items/nova-noma-gaia/NovaNoma-Gaia.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>

  <button id="ter">play &#9658;</button>
</div>
  <div class="textbox"></div>
  <div class="textbox_mute"></div>
```